# Looping with Duplicate Pasting

Tags: vba, loops, tweak

I have been working on a VBA code for the last week or so and can get about 5% away from the result that I require.

I have 2 worksheets:

Sheet1 - which has a list of data in E:E
 Sheet2 - which has a list of data in G2:G
 Both lists have matching values in the list.

What I am trying to do is check if each cell in sheet1 is in sheet2, if it is then copy and paste the data from that row into the relative row of sheet2's matched value. This bit I can do........Where I am struggling is when I have a single value in sheet1 but multiple values in sheet2. I only want to copy and paste the data across in one match but it will copy and paste the info across to both matches. Similarly if I have 2 values in sheet1 but only one value in sheet2 it overwrites the information.

Below I have shown the code I am using.

```
 Sub FillinAlegs()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Dim names As Range, name As Range, values As Range, value As Range, rng As Range

   Set values = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) '
   Set names = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G2:G" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) '
   For Each name In names
    For Each value In values
     If value.value = name.value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & value.Row & ":P" & value.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & name.Row & ":R" & name.Row)
     End If
    Next value
   Next name
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Please help me. I am pulling my hair out!

Thanks

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADnVQ.png)
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI684.png)

Comment: It's tough to understand what you mean `I have a single value in sheet1 but multiple values in sheet2` without seeing an example.

Comment: Hi Ashleedawg A B C D
1 Red Car Data Data Data
2 Blue Car Data Data Data

Comment: That's obviously not representative of 2 worksheets' data.  Also if you're adding more information relevant to the question, please [edit] the question to do so.  (Also, see "[mcve]" and [How to add sample data to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96127) (The link is for SQL data but the same could be applied here.)

Comment: Sorry, it is my first post and the comments didn't really work and when i clicked enter it wouldn't let me edit it for 5 minutes.. i have attached 2 screenshots which may be better to see. the data runs into the hundreds of rows but the concept is the same. thank you for taking the time to have a look through my problem, i do greatly appreciate it and sorry if it comes across abit amateurish.